# Passing from view to module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a my view set up to allow users to enter urls, and I have a module set up in my lib which basically parsers these urls entered by the user. How do I pass the url received in the view to this module in my lib dir?

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this,

Store the below code in "search_module.rb" under "lib" directory.

```
module SearchModule

  def get_size(search_key)

    search_key.gsub(/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/,"").squeeze.split.size

  end

end
```

Now I access this method in my search_controller.rb as follows,

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController

  include SearchModule

  @query_size = get_size(params[:query])

end
```

Now, the point is,

### Modules :

*Should contain methods that can be used in controllers to achieve a functionality.*

### Helpers:

*Should contain methods that can be used in views to format html.*